# Oracle SQL : Expand year to a full date

Tags: oracle10g

This must be simple to answer, but how do you expand in Oracle a year to a full date, e.g.

`1996` to `1996-01-01 00:00:00` ?

EDIT

The data type of the year is char, and I want to end up by comparing this year to a string-date, e.g.

`1996` <= `'1998-31-12 12:04:35'`

It is important that the expanded data is expanded in the same data Format (since I get the dates preformatted)

At the end I need something like this

`WHERE (  to_date(table.year_char ,'YYYY') <= '1996-12-31 00:00:00')`

or sth like this

`WHERE (  to_char(to_date(table.year_char ,'YYYY')) <= '1996-12-31 00:00:00')`

or anything which works

Comment: What data type is the year at the moment, and what data type do you want to end up with - a `DATE`, or a string in that format?

Comment: Good question : The data dtype of the year is char. I want to end up with a date.

Comment: "I get the dates pre formatted" - a `DATE` doesn't have a format, it has an internal representation. So the `1996-12-31 00:00:00` is a string, not a `DATE`?

Comment: You made me think (Im kind of newbie in SQL), and I have to revert my answer : it must be a string (I didn't know that string comparison like this functions with sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're starting with the year as a string and you want to end up with a `DATE` object, you use the `TO_DATE()` function; but you need to supply a dummy month or it'll default to the first day of the current month in the specified year:

```
select to_date('1996', 'YYYY') from dual;

May, 01 1996 00:00:00+0000
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6666c/136)

With the month, and to make it clearer the day too, appended and a suitable format model:

```
select to_date('1996' ||'-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual

January, 01 1996 00:00:00+0000
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6666c/138). I've left the year and the `'-01-01'` literal separate and concatenated on the assumption that you'll be using a variable really...

In a `WHERE` clause, using the sample date you initially showed:

```
select * from dual
where to_date('1996' ||'-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  <= to_date('1998-31-12 12:04:35', 'YYYY-DD-MM HH24:MI:SS')
```

Or if you're actually comparing to a string as your second example suggests, just leave it as a string, as you want both sides of the comparison to be the same data type without any implicit conversion that might cause you problems later. The string you have fortunately has the data in a format [that is comparable](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6666c/142):

```
WHERE (table.year_char || '-01-01 00:00:00' <= '1996-12-31 00:00:00')
```

You could [convert it to and back from a `DATE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6666c/141) but there isn't any benefit in doing so.

Comment: Thanks, my goal is to have something like this after it `WHERE (  to_date(table.year_char ,'YYYY') <= '1996-12-31 00:00:00')`

Comment: Some problems with the above though : `ORA-01861: literal does not match format string`

Comment: @HeinrichStack - in the final `WHERE (table.year_char || '-01-01 00:00:00' <= '1996-12-31 00:00:00')` version, neither side is a date, there is no date conversion, so that error can't be generated. Something doesn't add up. Are you sure the error is coming from that `WHERE` clause, not a date conversion somewhere else in the statement?

Comment: you are right, in the final it works fine. It came in the statement above. However, Im going to use the last version.